# Clarification: Is the Credential Manager login with google in android needs Digital asset link as mandatory

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin, credential-manager

I am trying to migrate the Google Sing with Android to Credential Managers Sign in with Google.

After the setup, shall I need the Digital Asset link as a mandatory one here.

Need to know any other sample docs available for this CredentialManager.